# No more threads can be created in the system

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am seeing a lot of error in the event viewer, Could anyone help me out
"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {9926D1CF- F158-418F-A9A2-B653B497D982} failed due to the following error: 800700a4 No more threads can be created in the system. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700A4)."

Comment: You need to provide more information about which COM component this relates to. Is it perhaps Tridion Content Manager?

Comment: Yes Tridion Content Manager